# Dijkstra algorithm~

Tags: c, dijkstra

[image: **enter image description here**]

If you apply the ijkstra algorithm several times, you can see the effect of the Floyd algorithm. We've created a program that uses the Dijkstra algorithm to get the shortest path from every vertex in the graph to every other vertex in the graph, and we've created a Dijkstra code.The values shown in the image are not shown. What is the reason?

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAX_VERTICES 100    
#define INF 1000000 

typedef struct GraphType {
    int n;  
    int weight[MAX_VERTICES][MAX_VERTICES];
} GraphType;

int distance[MAX_VERTICES];
int found[MAX_VERTICES];

int choose(int distance[], int n, int found[])

{
  int i, min, minpos;

  min = INT_MAX;
  minpos = -1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (distance[i] < min && !found[i]) {
        min = distance[i];
        minpos = i;
    }
 return minpos;
}

void print_status(GraphType* g)
{
static int step = 1;
printf("STEP %d: ", step++);
printf("distance: ");
for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++) {
    if (distance[i] == INF)
        printf(" * ");
    else
        printf("%2d ", distance[i]);

}
printf("\n");
printf("        found:    ");
for (int i = 0; i < g->n; i++)

    printf("%2d ", found[i]);

printf("\n\n");
}
void shortest_path(GraphType * g, int start)

{
int i, u, w;
for (i = 0; i < g->n; i++) 
{
    distance[i] = g->weight[start][i];
    found[i] = FALSE;
}
found[start] = TRUE; 
distance[start] = 0;
for (i = 0; i < g->n - 1; i++) {
    print_status(g);
    u = choose(distance, g->n, found);
    found[u] = TRUE;

    for (w = 0; w < g->n; w++)
        if (!found[w])

            if (distance[u] + g->weight[u][w] < distance[w])
                distance[w] = distance[u] + g->weight[u][w];

  }
}
 int main(void)
{
GraphType g = { 7,
{{ 0,  7,  INF, INF,   3,  10, INF },
{ 7,  0,    4,  10,   2,   6, INF },
{ INF,  4,    0,   2, INF, INF, INF },
{ INF, 10,    2,   0,  11,   9,   4 },
{ 3,  2,  INF,  11,   0, INF,   5 },
{ 10,  6,  INF,   9, INF,   0, INF },
{ INF, INF, INF,   4,   5, INF,   0 } }
};
for(int i=0; i<g.n; i++){
    printf("from %d to other nodes>\n", i);
    shortest_path(&g, i);
}
return  0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question. -- Please don't post text as image. Copy-and-paste it. -- Then it would be time to learn to debug. The most simple form is to insert `printf()` at interesting places and watch important values.

Comment: What do you mean by "The values shown in the image are not shown."? Other values? No values? More values? If different values than you expect, then what makes you expect them? can you spot any systematic pattern of incorrect values? Did you try debugging? ( Hmmm. Quite some buzzing going on here.... :-)  )

Comment: "The values shown in the image are not shown." Unable to parse. Are the values shown or not shown? As I reckon they can't be both show and not shown. Proper answer must be ["Mu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))